# Get the list of contacts added or deleted today

Tags: android

How could I access the list of contacts that are added/deleted today. I am using column `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP` to get list of contacts last updated, but this timestamp gets updated even if I made a call, so it returns the list of contacts that are contacted today.

But I want only the list of all those contacts that are added or deleted today.

Comment: `android.provider.ContactsContract.DeletedContactsColumns`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html

Check version field to identify whether contact is added first time. version value is incremented each time when you update any contact details.